# Probability of two or more transitions is o($\Delta$ t).

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Assume that $X_t$ is a continuous time Markov-chain with finite state space, and assume it is regular. That is:

> If $t_1<t_2\ldots <t_n $ then
>
> $P(X_{t_n}=i_n|X_{t_1}=i_1\cap X_{t_2}=i_2\cap\ldots \cap
>  X_{t_{n-1}}=i_{n-1})=P(X_{t_n}=i_n| X_{t_{n-1}}=i_{n-1})$.
>
> Define $P_{ij}(a,b)=P(X_b=j|X_a=i)$.
>
> For $i\ne j$ the quantity
>
> $\lim\limits_{\Delta t\rightarrow0^+}\frac{P_{ij}(t,t+\Delta
>  t)}{\Delta t}=\mu_{ij}(t)$, exists and is continuous in $t$.
>
> We also define
>
> $\nu _i(t)=\lim\limits_{\Delta
> t\rightarrow0^+}\frac{1-P_{ii}(t,t+\Delta t)}{\Delta t}$.

**Then some books say that the probability of two or more transitions in an intervel of length $\Delta t$ is $o(\Delta t)$. But how exactly is this proved?**

Comment: The probability distribution between transitions is exponentially distributed. Perhaps that helps?

Comment: @Math1000 Is that also the case when it is not a time-homogeneous Markov chain? As you can see the rates depend on $t$.

Comment: I have not studied time-inhomogeneous Markov chains, so I cannot help you there. Sorry.

Comment: @Math1000 No worries, thanks anyway for the comment.